# Coldfusion ORM EntityToQuery NullPointerException

Tags: orm, coldfusion, nullpointerexception, coldfusion-9

I am getting an error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

When I call:

```
<cfdump var="#posts#" top="2">
<cfset postsQuery = EntityToQuery(posts)>
```

dumping posts shows an array of objects as it should but for some reason the EntityToQuery(posts) is breaking.    The error message is not one of the normal ones which tell you what line it broke on etc. its just the following struct:

```
message:      [empty string]
StackTrace:   java.lang.NullPointerException 
TagContext:   array[empty]
Type:         java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? I think its data related but I don't know what to look for. Its only happening on one implementation of this code, not the others im working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange errors stopped the next time the coldfusion service was restarted.

So if anyone else has that problem.... give restarting cf a try